# unable to click "ok" on javascript alert after clicking logout in Microsoft edge selenium with java

Tags: java, selenium, microsoft-edge

```
try {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='javascript:confirmLogout()']")).click();      
    //unable to execute any code after this 
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();   
    System.out.println("hello");  // unable to print
//execution stops after logout click event
```

Comment: Please share the URL

Comment: share your error log

Comment: its not displaying any error..after clicking manually rest other code works ..when click event is happening JavaScript confirmLogout() function is coming and not able to click on Ok button

Comment: Please share the URL so i can help you, can i give you an example for the same

Comment: Yea @imsankalp89

Answer (score 0):

I suppose javascript fxn in @href is not getting executed, so you can invoke it explicitly using JavascriptExecutor as following, see if it works:

```
try {
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='javascript:confirmLogout()']")).click();   
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor ) driver;
    jse.executeScript("confirmLogout();");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();   
    System.out.println("hello");    
}
```